# Reactjs - adding classes to links

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs, before I start to include something like the jquery lib to do this - what would be the best way of adding a class to found links in a piece of text?

```
  const attachClassesToLinks = (htmlWithLinks) => {
    // do something special

    return htmlWithLinks
  }
```

so something like this

```
attachClassesToLinks('a piece of text with a <a href="/test">link</a> and another <a href="/test2">link2</a>')
```

a jquery like method

```
//$(htmlWithLinks).find('a').addClass('text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary')
```

Comment: How is that text included in your React Component

Comment: via a json feed

Comment: <p className='paragraph-margin-bottom-10 text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: attachClassesToLinks(lang.privacy[0].description) }} />

Comment: "description" : "Some text with a <a href=\"/de/datenschutz\">link</a> and another <a href=\"/de/cookie-richtlinie\">link</a>",

Comment: Option 1: DOMParser (according to feng shui). Option 2: replace (dirty, unreliable). Both easy to implement, the second simpler.

Comment: @dfsq - example? str.replace('a', 'a className="text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary") ?

Comment: const attachClassesToLinks = (htmlWithLinks) => {
    // do something special
    return htmlWithLinks.replace(/<a/g, '<a class="text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary"')
  }

Comment: yes. but it's not 100% reliable. but good enough i think

Comment: what do you guys think - its a bit borky --

Comment: Whats the DomParser verison

Comment: Write them manually.

Comment: - write what manually?